# ScrollDown and scrollUp event in Testcafe

Tags: angular, scroll, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How can i perform the **scrollDown** and **scrollUp** the browser page in **TestCafe** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe performs scroll automatically when you call any action. For example if you need to scroll to some element you can use the hover action here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/hover.html

Comment: Have you tried this?

export const scroll = ClientFunction((selector: string, options: ScrollToOptions) => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (elem) {
    elem.scrollBy(options);
  }
});

Comment: No its not working when i passed my grid name as a selector for this it could show the error to me

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround : Click on one of the element on page which is under viewport and then use `t.presskey('pagedown')`